# Issue when try to upload file using ktor client

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I got java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream when try to upload img file to server

```
val response = httpClient.submitFormWithBinaryData(
            url = BASE_URL + "files/upload",
            formData = formData {
                append("image", file!!.readBytes(), Headers.build {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=\"ktor_logo.png\"")
                })
            }
        )
```

How to solve that ?

Comment: Can you share the endpoint to which you're trying to make the request?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Unfortunately, no, is it crusial ? As i see, it's local exception, there no any request to backend

Comment: Yes, because the `ProtocolException` is a network exception.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I've fixed that, after removing network inspecting interceptor which i add to ktor client